# How can I pass JS objects from the server-side to the clientside in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

In PHP I used to pass objects from the backend to the front end in JSON form, using script tags.

```
<script>

var serversideStuff = '<?php echo json_encode($serversideArray); ?>';

</script>
```

**How can I pass JS objects from the server-side to the clientside using nodeJS, express and Jade.** There is probably a really good way that I'm just not aware of.

Hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var clientVar = {{JSON.stringify(serverVar)}}
</script>
```

change {{}} to whatever your template engine uses to interpret code

Answer (score 5):

In PHP you use bad practices (dynamically generating javascript as part of an application).

With node you do it right. This means you

- Either write the data to the HTML (How would your website work without javascript, you are using progressive enhancement, right?)
- Expose that data as a web service you talk to over Ajax or WebSockets

Comment: Raynos is absolutely right, to expand slightly on his answer. Check the res. and req. information in the Express guide http://expressjs.com/guide.html also read up on Expresses local variables and how they work in Jade.

Comment: So if I have a JavaScript object constructed on the server-side how would I get this object to the client-side. Could I use HTML5 data attributes? A little snippet would be greatly appreciated. I would prefer not to have to call a separate request after page load.

Comment: @pagewil depends on templating language. Just pass it in to your jade locals hash and render it in the template, again it really depends on what the data is and where it belongs. There is not a generic solution to this. It depends on semantics, you do the most semantically correct thing for the particular item of data

Comment: @Raynos I understand how I can place single bit of data into html data attr `<div data-mydata='#{myobject.dataChunk1}'></div>` but don't understand how to get the whole contents of an object onto the client-side. eg. `<div data-mydata='#{myobject}'></div>` would render to => `<div data-mydata='[object-object]'></div>`

Comment: @pagewil you should not be dumping objects into html. That is bad, you should place semantic values into html. Basically redesign it so it isnt a hack

Comment: @Raynos can you please give a very brief example or point me towards an example?

Comment: @pagewil data specific, what is the _exact_ data you want to share.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4166/discussion-between-raynos-and-pagewil)